# How can I manually extract Metadata from mp4 Videoframes?

Tags: ffmpeg, gps, metadata, mp4, gopro

I have a large GoPro Video about 11:44 min. Each second the GoPro records 30 frames with datetime(UNIX) and gps(lat, long) information. So there are round about 21188 frames in my video.

I need to extract the GPS data to bring every single frame to a map. There's a tool called GoProtelemetryextractor (https://goprotelemetryextractor.com/free/). This gives me a csv file with 19800 lines (1 line for each frame). Obviously there are 1400 rows/frames missing in the csv. If I now multiplex the csv with the mp4 in a GIS software, the frames get assigned to wrong "csv frames". I need to match these 19800 frames correctly to the frames in the video by deleting "None metadata frames" out of the video.
I guess the problem is that the goprotelemetry extractor starts writing the csv with the first metadata it finds. And not starting at the first frame and just write "NO METADATA ROWS".

**Basically my question is: How can I extract the metadata from each mp4 Frame "manually" to know where the csv "starts" and match video and csv?**

Comment: Can you provide a short sample video?

Comment: unfortunately the video is very long/big and I dont know how to cut it without losing the metadata. I tried to cut with common freeware but then it wasnt poosible anymore to use some kind of telemtryextractor...

Comment: @bennimueller Have you ever managed to solve this?